# Find links in string

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

I've found a page with a list of regular expressions that test for valid url's.
http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

The one from Diego Pernini seems the be the best choice.
https://gist.github.com/729294

Now I just can't get this regex to work with finding a url in a string.

I want to isolate the url in this string:

```
$string = 'Really digging new the twitter design! http://t.co/71dEuIY8';
```

This regex gives me 0

```
preg_match_all('%^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)*(?:\.[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,6}))(?::\d+)?(?:[^\s]*)?$%iu', $string, $match);
```

It does match a valid url when I use a string which only contains a url:

```
$string = 'http://t.co/71dEuIY8';
```

How do I tweak this regex to isolate a valid url, or urls, in a string with more than just a url?

Comment: asked many times before, search first.

Comment: See any [regexp analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%7Cftp%29%3A//%29%28%3F%3A%5CS+%28%3F%3A%3A%5CS*%29%3F@%7C%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%7B3%7D%7C%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%5Ba-z%5Cd%5Cx%7B00a1%7D-%5Cx%7Bffff%7D%5D+-%3F%29*%5Ba-z%5Cd%5Cx%7B00a1%7D-%5Cx%7Bffff%7D%5D+%29%28%3F%3A%5C.%28%3F%3A%5Ba-z%5Cd%5Cx%7B00a1%7D-%5Cx%7Bffff%7D%5D+-%3F%29*%5Ba-z%5Cd%5Cx%7B00a1%7D-%5Cx%7Bffff%7D%5D+%29*%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Ba-z%5Cx%7B00a1%7D-%5Cx%7Bffff%7D%5D%7B2%2C6%7D%29%29%28%3F%3A%3A%5Cd+%29%3F%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5Cs%5D*%29%3F&env=env_perl)

Comment: Those regular expressions aren't intended to be used to find URLs in a string, they're meant to verify that a string is a valid URL. What do you actually want to do? Do you want to, say, find URLs in text and turn them into links? That regular expression fails on `www.example.com` and `http://www.google.com?q=test`, for example, both of which work perfectly fine in any browser's address bar. It will also parse trailing punctuation to be part of a URL. E.g. in `Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions!`, the `!` will be part of the URL, which will make you end up at a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the ^ at the start and the $ at the end.
These mean the link must start and end this way.  That is why it matches the isolated link but not in the string.

Comment: this happens when someone just made some copy/paste for URL validation with regexp and tries to use it for different purposes without actually understand what that regexp does.